# Stopping mocking in Jmockit

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, jmockit, expectations

I am using JMockit. I am mocking a method. I want that mocked method should be called once after that actual method should be called. I am providing the code I am using.

```
package StopMocking;
public class ClassToMock 
{
    public int methodToMock()
    {
        return 2;
    }
}
```

This is the class I am testing

```
package StopMocking;
public class ClassToTest 
{
    public void methodToTest()
    {
        ClassToMock classToMockInstance = new ClassToMock();
        System.out.println(""+classToMockInstance.methodToMock());
    }
}
```

This is the test class.

```
package StopMocking;
import org.junit.Test;
import mockit.Mocked;
import mockit.NonStrictExpectations;
public class TestAClass 
{
    @Mocked("methodToMock") ClassToMock classToMockMockedInstance;
    @Test
    public void test1()
    {

        new Expectations(classToMockMockedInstance)
        {
            {
            classToMockMockedInstance.methodToMock();returns(1);
            }
        };

        (new ClassToTest()).methodToTest();
        //Some code for stoping mocking
        (new ClassToTest()).methodToTest();//It should display 2

    }
}
```

When I am using new Expectations(classToMockMockedInstance) it is throwing this exception

```
mockit.internal.MissingInvocation: Missing invocation of:
StopMocking.ClassToMock#methodToMock()
   on mock instance: StopMocking.ClassToMock@15093f1
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: Missing invocation
    at StopMocking.ClassToMock.methodToMock(ClassToMock.java)
    at StopMocking.TestAClass$1.<init>(TestAClass.java:21)
    at StopMocking.TestAClass.test1(TestAClass.java:18)
    ... 6 more
```

Comment: Can't you just write two tests, one with mocking and the other without?

Comment: Thanks for your interest @Rogério. You are right I can write two test cases in this particular example. But this is a sceneario. I want to know that if there is any functionality is available in JMockit or any other option with that I mocked method will be called only once after that original method will be called.

Comment: Yes, you can record a *strict* expectation on a partially mocked instance: `new Expectations(someObj) { ... }`. Only the first invocation will match this expectation; any additional calls will execute the real code. Another way is to use a `Delegate` object with a conditional call to `proceed()` in the delegate method, which would have a first parameter of type `Invocation`. I won't provide examples here, as the official documentation has plenty of those.

Comment: Thank you @Rogério. when I am using Expectations(ClassToMockMockedInstance). It is throwing this exception.

Comment: I have edited the question with exception

Comment: Yes, because the test is mocking a specific instance of `ClassToMock`, but this instance is not the one used by the class under test; you either need to pass the mocked instance to `ClassToTest`, *or* tell JMockit to partially mock *all* instances of `ClassToMock` by passing the class literal: `new Expectations(ClassToMock.class) { ... }`.

Comment: Thank you @Rogério Please add this comment in answer, I will accept the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to write the test is to as follows, using partial mocking and strict expectations:

```
public class TestAClass 
{
    @Test
    public void test1()
    {
        final ClassToMock classToMockInstance = new ClassToMock();

        new Expectations(ClassToMock.class) {{
            classToMockInstance.methodToMock(); result = 1;
        }};

        new ClassToTest().methodToTest(); // prints "1"

        // This time the real method implementation will be executed:
        new ClassToTest().methodToTest(); // prints "2"
    }
}
```

Comment: Another question, How to paritally mock a interface. When I pass an interface name in Expectations it throws IllegalArgumentException. Thank you

Comment: Partially mock an interface? Normally, you don't. Partial mocking through `Expectations` is only meant for classes, which contain implementation code.